# Pass the RecycleView button to SecondFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I created a button on my RecycleItem, and I want my FirstFragment to do the respective navigation.

In my RecyclerView, I have an ImageView and a button called 'details'. The image is taken from my API, and I want, when I click the 'details' button, to move to SecondFragment and display the details of the image.

I added my RecycleItem in FirstFragment, but when I try to call the button ID to do the navigation, the program says it doesn't recognize the ID in FirstFragment.kt.

I have also created my custom adapter, where I call the API items.

**RecycleItem.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detalhes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Detalhes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"/>`
```

**FistFragment.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/recycleView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FistFrament.kt**

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    //private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var adapter:CustomAdapter? = null
    private val viewModel: BobBurgerViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.getData()
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        adapter = CustomAdapter(requireContext())
        binding.recycleView.adapter = adapter
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            viewModel.rocketsFlow.collectLatest {
                adapter?.items = it.body() ?: emptyList()
            }
        }
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: RecyclerItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Characters>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Characters, newItem: Characters): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Characters, newItem: Characters): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallback)
    var items: List<Characters>
        get() = differ.currentList
        set(value) {
            differ.submitList(value)
        }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            RecyclerItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.apply {
            val item = items[position]
            textView.text = item.name


            Glide.with(context)
                .load(item.image)
                .into(imageView)
        }
        holder.binding.imageView

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a lambda function into your adapter:

In your customAdapter constructor:

```
class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context, private val onClick: (Characters) -> Unit)
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder()` add this:

```
detalhes.setOnClickListener { onClick(item) }
```

Finally, in your `FirstFragment`:

```
adapter = CustomAdapter(requireContext()) {
    // You will get your clicked Character here, do your navigation and pass it as an argument
}
```